# recover source code of silverlight application

Tags: .net, silverlight

Unfortunately I have deleted the source of my silverlight application. I have only files of its deployed version. Is there a way to recover source files from this deployed version. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Adrian Faciu: Off-topic advertising...

Comment: @leppie - sorry, i was just trying to help, i've removed my comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess an [IL decompiler](http://www.program-transformation.org/Transform/DotNetDecompilers) is what you need

Answer (score 1):

You could download the container. Then unzip/uncab, and view the source via Reflector .NET, but it could be messy.